# AngularJs: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

guys!

I am working on some Angular code from another person, and I am trying to figure stuff out. I updated libraries, using bower (because I needed some newer version to finish off the work) and I've got an error from Angular, on my homepage. The error is as follows: "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined". I tried to debug it but no success. I also read a lot about it in here but nothing helped me. From what I've read the problem could be in the app .config() or in a wrongly declared controller, or ... who knows :D

If you'd like to try and help me, I will provide important (in my opinion) bits of code:

1) App configuretion:

```html
'use strict';
var agencySeekApp = angular.module('agencySeekApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'flang', 'ngCookies', 'agencySeekFilters'])
      .value('toastr', toastr)
      .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
        });

        var routeUserChecks = {
          adminRole: {
            authenticate: function(auth) {
              return auth.isAuthorizedForRole('admin');
            }
          },
          authenticated: {
            authenticate: function(auth) {
              return auth.isAuthenticated();
            }
          }
        };

        $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomePageCtrl'
          })
          .when('/category/:categoryId/choose-network/', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/network_pick.html',
            controller: 'ChooseNetworkCtrl'
          })
          .when('/category/:categoryId/network/:networkId', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/schools_pick.html',
            controller: 'SchoolPageCtrl'
          })
          .when('/agencies/:categoryId/:schoolId', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/agency.html',
            controller: 'AgencyPageCtrl'
          })
          .when('/show/agency/:agencyId', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/agency_show.html',
            controller: 'ShowAgencyCtrl'
          })
          .when('/show/school/:schoolId', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/school_show.html',
            controller: 'ShowSchoolCtrl'
          })
          .when('/case/open', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/open_case.html',
            controller: 'OpenCaseCtrl'
          })
          .when('/case/show/:case_id', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/show_case.html',
            controller: 'ShowCaseCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/retrivePassword', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account.html',
            controller: 'AccountPageCtrl'
          })
          .when('/search/:search_params',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/search_page.html',
            controller: 'SearchPageCtrl'
          }).when('/postcode-agencies/category/:categoryId/postcode-id/:postCodeId',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/post_code_agencies.html',
            controller: 'PostCodeAgenciesCtrl'
          })
        /*for delete*/
          .when('/sysadmin/network',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/sys_admin_network.html',
            controller: 'SysAdminNetworkCtrl'
          })
          .when('/sysadmin/categories',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/sys_admin_categories.html',
            controller: 'SysAdminCategoriesCtrl'
          })
          .when('/sysadmin/list',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/sys_admin_list.html',
            controller: 'SysAdminListCtrl'
          })
          .when('/sysadmin/users',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/sys_admin_users.html',
            controller: 'SysAdminUsersCtrl'
          })
        /*end*/
        /*account*/
          .when('/account/cases',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account_cases.html',
            controller: 'AccountCasesCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/teachers',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account_teachers.html',
            controller: 'AccountTeachersCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/schools',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account_schools.html',
            controller: 'AccountSchoolsCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/agencies',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account_agencies.html',
            controller: 'AccountAgenciesCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/case_workers',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account_councilors.html',
            controller: 'AccountCouncilorsCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/linking',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account_linking.html',
            controller: 'AccountLinkingCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/handshaking',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account_handshaking.html',
            controller: 'AccountHandshakingCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/myprofile',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/my_profile.html',
            controller: 'AccountProfileCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/report',{
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account_report.html',
            controller: 'AccountReportCtrl'
          })
          .when('/account/admin-settings', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/account_admin_settings.html',
            controller: 'AccountAdminSettingsCtrl'
          })

        /*end*/
          .otherwise({
            templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
            controller: 'in_Otherwise'
          });
      });
```

2) Homepage controller:

```html
angular.module('agencySeekApp')
  .controller('HomePageCtrl',['$scope','identity','$http','selectedSchoolCookieService',function($scope,identity,$http,selectedSchoolCookieService){
    //$scope.test = 'some test';
    $scope.identity = identity;
    $http.get('/api/v1/agency/categories')
      .success(function(res){
        console.log("res : ",res);
        $scope.arr = res.data;
      })
      .error();

    var url = '';
    var schoolIdCookie = selectedSchoolCookieService.getCookie('schoolId');
    $scope.urlForTheUser = function (someId) {
      if(identity.currentUser && identity.currentUser.isFromSchool() ){
        url = '/agencies/'+someId+'/'+identity.currentUser.school_id+'/';
      }else {
        if(schoolIdCookie) {
          url = '/agencies/' + someId + '/' + schoolIdCookie;
        }else {
          url = '/category/'+someId+'/choose-network/';
        }
      }
      return url;
    };
```

3) The scripts section from my index.html, including all the scripts (for inclusion order reference):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/charts/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/charts/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/charts/jquery.flot.spline.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jRate-master/dist/jRate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/toastr/toastr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/flangCharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/auth.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/identity.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/LoginController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/usersResource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/services/selectedAgencies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/services/pageService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/services/selectedSchoolCookieService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/services/lastPageCategorySelected.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/directives/fileUploadDirective.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/directives/popUpAgencyDirective.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/directives/popUpLinkingDirective.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/directives/reportDirectives.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/filters.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/HomePageCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/ChooseNetworkCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/ShowAgencyCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/SchoolPageCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/AgencyPageCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/ShowAgencyCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/OpenCaseCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/SearchPageCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/ShowCaseCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/ShowSchoolCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/LeftSideBarCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/PostCodeAgenciesCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers/AccountAdminSettingsCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/SysAdminNetworkCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/SysAdminListCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/SysAdminUsersCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/SysAdminCategoriesCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountCasesCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountTeachersCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountSchoolsCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountAgenciesCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountCouncilorsCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountLinkingCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountMenuCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountHandshakingCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountProfileCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/user_page_ctrl/AccountReportCtrl.js"></script>
```

Hope that is enough!

Best regards,
H.

Comment: Debugged a little bit, using Chrome dev tools, as per @bilpor's suggestion. The problem happens on line 5 of the HomePageCtrl.js, when calling $http.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. When calling the $http, I should chain a .success() callback and a .error(). The problem is that the .error() expects an function argument, and I am supplying nothing. What fixed is was:

```
 .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log(data, status, headers, config);
  });
```

That was it :)

Thanks for the tip on breakpoints. I can't believe I didn't do that and just ran to StackOverflow crying :D

Anyway, It's done. Thanks to @bilpor for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from this. Have you tried stepping the code to try and narrow the line that it doesn't like. You should be able to use the Chrome browser tools and set breakpoints etc. I'm assuming from your first piece of code that

> 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'flang', 'ngCookies', 'agencySeekFilters'

are present

Comment: your answer should be a comment and your answer is not at all solution of question..

Comment: Apart from dissing my attempt, it would be helpful if you moved my answer to a comment and perhaps provided something constructive to this thread

Comment: I appreciate your effort but thing you should understand difference between a solution and suggestion.If @bitstream is fully satisfied with your answer then i will even upvote your answer.

Comment: @ShubhamNigam it helped a lot, now I know more about my issue :) But it's not an answer, I still have this problem :)

Comment: Maybe Shubham can at least upvote this back to 0 now. As you can see from my profile Im new to stackoverflow and didn't notice the small comment button and went straight to the answer button